Xubuntu loopback from USB soundcard IN to HDMI monitor OUT (pulse audio)?
Running a Xubuntu desktop with pulse audio as default.
My PC has 2 sound cards:

One USB for a Shortwave radio set
One onboard card with no connections bar my HDMI monitor

Both are driven by pulse audio it seems.
Presently the default audio OUT path is the speakers on my monitor
When I plug the USB sound card into the radio, the internal radio speaker is
disconnected. there is no apparent software option to disable that muting in the radio.
(FT-847)
I therefore want to loopback the incoming audio from the USB sound card, and play it back, in near real time, from the HDMI monitor speakers.
I can load the loopback module from the shell but try as I might I cannot
work out:

How to enable the loopback in the XFCE pulse audio settings taskbar widget?
How to persist that as the default scenario on system boot?

Annoyingly FLDIGI (a radio decoder app) can do this from the menu options within the program, but none of my other apps appear to be able to do this internally so I have to set it at the system level.

Starting point is your release details; as Ubuntu makes changes to the internals of the OS as the linux kernel changes & advances; with Xubuntu's interface sitting above these changes. Some stacks use PipeWire underneath, but Pulse Audio controls on the front (user) end; but release details are the starting point to understanding the software stack you're working with.

Apologies!
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
